# Use typeahead.js to populate list using XML file

Tags: javascript, xml

I actually don't know where to start with this, as the documentation doesn't really explain much.

I'd like to generate an autocomplete list using an external XML file that I load up in my site.

So far I've got this applied to the input field:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    highlight: true
},
{
    name: 'brands',
    display: 'value',
    source: function(query, syncResults, asyncResults) {
        $.get('/?s=' + query, function(data) {
            asyncResults(data);
        });
    }
});
```

After searching, I see extra GET requests appear for each letter of the search query. But then in the console I see the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in <!DOC - jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in <!DOC
```

Not too sure what this means :S

I want to set http://services.inveroak.co.uk/readerimages/livepanel/91112.xml as the source XML file to read from, and then display various values from the XML as entries are typed in. I then want to perform a jump to a URL when these entries are clicked.

Am I using the right tool for the job?

Comment: _"and then display various values from the XML"_ What should be values searched for within `xml` file?

Comment: A 404 error is pretty unambiguous. What is the URL that would lead to the desired response?

Comment: Well specifically I want to search by `Name` and `Pin`, maybe others in future, b ut only those two initially. Is this required? or could the entire file be searched?

Comment: @Tomalak - Well when an entry is clicked, I'm looking to go to `/readers/[Pin]` - where Pin is the value from the XML file

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. You want the user to type stuff, and typeahead.js will turn that typing into HTTP requests. I'm not sure where XML comes into play yet. Should the browser fetch the entire XML and search it client-side? Or should the server accept search requests and return results that it pulled out of the XML? It's one of those two variants. For the former variant your don't need Ajax, for the latter you don't need client-side XML.

Comment: I want to be able to search the XML file, and return results if found, then when clicking on a result in a list, to go to the URL I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Ahh the latest edit explains it better. The client should pull the XML on demand and do searches locally.

Comment: Unless the URL in question is on the same domain as your application, you will not be able to fetch it from the client side. Is that a concern for you?

Comment: Yes, the XML file is on a different domain, I can already parse it and create an array of the bits I need. Maybe I should try something like this? https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: Well, use the widget that you find most pleasant to use. But I don't really see how you are able to fetch that XML from a different domain. This conflicts with the same-origin-policy and browsers prevent it.

Comment: If you decide to go with typeahead, i think the smartest way forward is t dig into the [bloodhound documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md) and create a custom search provider for your XML file. It's not all that difficult to do. After that you can connect that new provider to a vanilla typeahead setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.get()`, `$.map()`, `input` event, modified version of `typeahead.js` [`substringMatcher`](https://gist.github.com/jharding/9458744#file-the-basics-js) function

```
$(function() {
  var source; // source `.xml`
  var substringMatcher = function(strs, q, cb) {
    return (function(q, cb, name) {
      var matches, substrRegex;

      // an array that will be populated with substring matches
      matches = [];

      // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
      substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

      // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
      // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
      $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
        if (substrRegex.test(str)) {

          matches.push(name(str));
        }
      });

      cb(matches);
    }(q, cb, function(res) {
      return res
    }));
  };
  $.get("data.xml") // get `xml` source
    .then(function(xml) {
      // define `source` as array containing `.textContent`
      // of `Name` elements
      source = $.map($(xml).find("Name"), function(node) {
        return node.textContent 
      });
      return source
    })
    .then(function(src) {   
      // `source` is defined, use `input` event to 
      // pass current `input` value to `substringMatcher` function
      $(".typeahead").on("input", function(e) {   
        substringMatcher(src, e.target.value, function(results) {
          // display results
          $("#results ul").empty();
          $.map(results, function(value, index) {
            $("#results ul")
              .append($("<li />", {
                "class": "results-" + index,
                "html": value
              }))
          })
        })
      });
    })
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/VsHft9g74XczO1yrSJW7?p=preview